# Selecting proper tiles for the floor in the hall

Tags: flooring, tile, floor

*NB. I'm a total noob when it comes to home improvement so it's both fine and preferred to answer me like if I'm a retarded banana. Understanding my ignorance I have a lot of respect for the competence needed and I'm afraid of making choices that I'll regret later on. (I have a guy to help me but I'd like to understand what's going on and learn myself.)*

In my hall, I'd like to put tiles and I can't decide between different parameters (specified below) because I don't understand the implications of the choice. Asking in the store lead to recommendation that is suspectedly pricey.

1. Color: I'd go for dark/black because the dirt won't show as easily as on bright tiles.
2. Filling: I'd go with bright one (but not too bright) to create some contrast and enhance the grid pattern.
3. Size: Here I'm stuck. What are pros and cons of large/medium/small tiles?
4. Format: Here I'm stuck. What are pros and cons of squares/rectangles?
5. Texture: Here I'm unsure. Personally, I'd prefer some uneven-ness but not abrasive. What is downside of that, if anything?
6. Pricing: I've been told that the price range is due to quality. But I'm not sure how it works. It's not that I'll be riding a horse with horseshoes on it. How fragile is a tile of lower quality?

The last item is the most confusing. I prefer to lower the cost, of course, but I definitely don't want to go and cheap myself into problems. Please advise. (The fact is that the cheapest tiles they had is around 10$ and others are around 25$-120$. And I kind of liked the cheapest the best...)

Comment: The question is far too broad and covers cost, both of which are off-topic. Please revise to ask just one clear question and remove cost-related questions. You're welcome to ask more than one question in separate posts.

Comment: @isherwood It's not so much a question about price as such but rather of the quality following of premium materials. However, I do agree that it was a bit wide anyway, so I'm not challenging that. Thanks, mate.

Comment: We'd like to help, of course. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) for suggestions with getting this reopened or posting a new question.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for the link. Luckily I got an answer that seems reliable addresses all the question marks I had. In the future, I'll try to ask more granularly and non-broadly. I'm very new to the home improvement as such so my tries should be expected to be clumsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you buy a tile that is sold as a "floor tile". Some tiles are only suitable for walls (sold as "wall tiles") and won't survive the abrasion caused by being walked on. Most tiles are sold as "wall/floor tiles" and are suitable for either.

1. Colour. Go for whatever you fancy. This is basically a cosmetic decision. More expensive tiles should be less likely to stain, but it's difficult to know.
2. Filling. I assume you mean Grout? I.e. the thing that fills in between the tiles. Again this is mostly a cosmetic decision. But in terms of staining, grout is in general less durable than tile. A light grout on the floor is likely to darken over time. This may be an issue, as it'd discolour more in the more highly trafficked areas.
3. Size. Mainly cosmetic, but there are other considerations.

   - If your floor is deliberately not flat (mainly applies to shower cubicle floors rather than hallways) then smaller tiles can follow the curve much more easily than big ones.
   - If your floor is unintentionally not flat then big tiles require more care to lay well (a small angle change due to an imperfection, when extended over a long tile becomes a big vertical change, meaning adjacent tiles don't meet each other properly. This can be avoided by proper preparation before tiling.)
   - A good tiler should make sure that there is adhesive supporting the whole tile. Poor tilers who only dab adhesive onto part of the tile risk the unadhesived part being unsupported, leading to cracking when the unsupported part is loaded. With bigger distances on bigger tiles, this could be more of a problem. But, as said, with a good tiler it wouldn't be an issue anyway.
4. Format/ pattern of tile shape. Completely cosmetic.
5. Texture. If you buy perfectly smooth tiles, then any imperfection in tile laying is more obvious. If you have a bumpier tile, then imperfections in laying are less obvious. Also a smooth shiny tile shows up scratches, whereas a rough bumpy tile will tend to hide them.
6. Pricing. Your guess is as good as mine. Across every product of any type I've ever bought, I've hoped that more money means better quality. But it doesn't. Sure, there's some correlation, but it's impossible for me to say that because product A costs X times what product B costs that it'll last for Y times as long.

Comment: Wonderfully put. My warmest appreciation to your effort. One follow up to that. I'm going with rather large tiles, 30x60cm (so 1x2ft, roughly). The cracking up you mention - are we talking something that occurs after a few months? Or can I simply walk around, stamp a bit here and there and then determine the quality? (I'm a non-tiny dude of 128kg, i.e. a bit below 300lbs, so the stampy test should be good enough.)

Comment: The cracking would be an issue straight away if the tiles weren't properly supported, so yes a good stampy test would make sure the tiler wasn't a DIY bodger. (Not that I have anything against DIY bodgers, being one myself, but if you're paying someone you expect them to know what they're doing, rather than learning by making mistakes on your project.)